# VM to VM communication between two ESXi hosts on the same LAN

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi

I have two ESXi 4 hosts on the same network, which has the following details:

```
HOST1:
IP: X.X.79.210
Subnet: 255.255.255.240
Gateway: X.X.79.209

HOST2:
IP: X.X.80.82
Subnet: 255.255.255.248
Gateway: X.X.80.81
```

I have VMs which has the following details:

```
VM1 in HOST1 (IpCop):
IP(ext): X.X.79.211
IP(int): 192.168.0.11
Subnet: 255.255.255.0

VM2 in HOST1:
IP: 192.168.0.2
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.11

VM3 in HOST2:
IP: 192.168.0.3
Subnet: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.0.11
```

How can I set it up such that VM3 will be able to communicate with both VM1 and VM2 in HOST1?

I've been thinking of setting the gateway of HOST2 to be the same with HOST1. Will this work? Will I still be able to connect to HOST2 using vSphere client?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing magical happens on a network because you virtualise some of the machines. If you want these two virtual machines to communicate with each other, you will need to connect their two networks together in exactly the same way as you would have done before, whatever that would have been (routed networking, VPN, etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you want two computers to communicate over the network, they must be able to reach each other on the IP level.

This means either both are connected to a router that routes traffic for both networks, or both have IP addresses that lie in the same broadcast domain (or subnet.)

I find it curious that you feel the need to redact the *private* IP addresses used on VMware hosts - what is secret about those private IP addresses ?

Answer (score 0):

The key here is that host1 and host2 are in different subnets which indicates that they are not on the same network. Bridged VMs networking is independant of their hosts so in order to communicate there must be a route from one VM to another. Simply putting them on the same subnet is like putting my home pc on the same subnet as your home pc and expecting them to magically see each other.

Depending on your situation you need to put the VMs in 2 subnets with either routable IPs or if you want to keep them seperate from your network setup a tunnel between host1 and host2, pointing your VM gateways to them.